# How to use interface MyCssResource in Utility class (GWT/ GWTP)?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I have

```
public interface MyResource extends ClientBundle{
    @NotStrict
    @Source("/myResource.css")
    MyCssResource css();
}
public interface MyCssResource extends CssResource {
      String gridEvenRow();
      String gridOddRow();
      .... more styling here....
}
```

in TestView.java

```
@UiField MyResource res;
@Inject
    public TestView(final Binder binder) {
        widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);
        res.css().ensureInjected();
    }
```

In TestPresenter.java, I can style Grid without any problem.

```
for (int i = 1; i < myGrid.getRowCount(); i++) {
    if((i%2) == 0){
          myGrid.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(i, getView().getRes().css().gridEvenRow());
    }
    else{
          myGrid.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(i, getView().getRes().css().gridOddRow());
    }
}
```

But I don't want to repeat this code every time I initialize a Grid. So I want to put this code into a Utility class so that I can use it by just 1 line of code. `Utility.formatGridOddEvenRow(myGrid);`

Here is code in Utility

```
public class Utility {

    public static MyResource res;
    public Utility(){
         res.css().ensureInjected();
    }

    public static void formatGridOddEvenRow(Grid grid){
        for (int i = 1; i < grid.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if((i%2) == 0){
                grid.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(i, res.css().gridEvenRow());
            }
            else{
                grid.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(i, res.css().gridOddRow());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it got run-time error `[ERROR] - Uncaught exception escaped` ? or some kind of error i don't know.

so, How to use interface MyCssResource in Utility class (GWT/ GWTP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final MyResource res=GWT.create(MyResource.class)
static{res.css().ensureInjected()}
```

add this code anywhere and use it. if you give all of your code, may be more helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope constructor is not called can you check place an alert and see is ensureInjected() is called.

As per Java Static method calling doesn't need object creation. so Utility Object is not created so constructor will not be called.

For GWT CssResources it is must ensureInjected() called before applying the css.

Comment: i put MyResource res=new MyResource();
  res.css().ensureInjected(); inside the static medthod & found that interface can not be created, so it could be we don't know how to use interface